# IPTable rules for transparent outbound proxy

Tags: iptables, curl

I've recently installed MITMProxy (similar to Squid) which I'm currently using to route outbound HTTP requests from my Ubuntu machine to another server (adding a header along the way).

When I use Linux's curl command line tool, and `export HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8080`, it correctly routes the traffic through the proxy.

What I'm trying to achieve is a transparent proxy, so that the environment variable doesn't need to be set. AFAICS, this means using *iptables* to route outbound packets from the machine through the proxy, yet the rules I'm setting do not seem to re-route to the proxy.

I'm calling:

```
# iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
# curl -v http://172.17.8.101:45000/player/2
```

Why might this not function correctly?